# Local database does not submit changes after insert into in Visual Studio/C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq, linq-to-sql

I have this problem with Visual Studio. I have a Service Based Database - KCSDatabase.mdf and 1 table in it- Users. I use it to create a LINQ class of it by drag and drop the table in the context of my UserDataClasses.cs. I have one Stored Procedure `AddNewUser` in the database and in UserDataClasses.cs too.

For connection it uses the connection string defined at `App.config`:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\KCSDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

So, when I submit a form with user data from registration and debug the app the database does not update the changes after insert into.

When I try to add two rows at one session with unique ids - it get me the notification that I can not insert because of the primary key (id) and does not make the changes in database. But if I do it at two separate times - two times I start the app and insert user with same id and it doesn't notify me and it does not make the changes at database too.

Somebody says me that it writes somewhere the inserting information (in some file, which is destroyed after closing the app) but does not insert in in the database.
This is the code of saveButtonClick event of my form:

```
UserDataClassesDataContext dc = new UserDataClassesDataContext();

dc.AddNewUser(Convert.ToInt32(tbId.Text),
              tbFirstName.Text,
              tbMiddleName.Text,
              tbLastName.Text,
              tbMail.Text,
              tbUserName.Text,
              tbPassword.Text);
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: We're going to need more details about the "create a LINQ class of it by drag and drop the table": this could be either LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework Model First (both are based on the use of designers to generate the client side code): which are you using?

Comment: I used LINQ to SQL. I do that: in my folder Data - right click -> Add New Item  LINQ to SQL Classes and named it as UserDataClasses.dbml. Then from the Server Exlorer drag the table Users and drop it in the blank field of the dbml file, similar drag and dropping I did with the stored procedure.

Comment: Check the connection string of the Web.Config where the Service is hosted.

Comment: I am not sure my app has a web.Config file - it is not a web application.

Comment: And it shouldn't have, you should have App.config. Can you query against the connection you have so we can be sure it's not the connection? Do some simple SELECT or something. Also paste your App.config.

Comment: I execute this code just to try the connection 
**SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::KidControlSystem.Properties.Settings.Default.KCSDbConnectionString);
              string sqlStr = "SELECT firstName from Users where id=2";
SqlCommand exeSql = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, cn);
              exeSql.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        exeSql.Connection.Open();
 Object obj = exeSql.ExecuteScalar();
            MessageBox.Show("the name is: " + obj.ToString());**
The connection is OK - I see the right name in the messagebox.

Comment: In my App.config file i have: 
**  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="KidControlSystem.Properties.Settings.KCSDbConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\KCSDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source = |SQL/CE|" />
  </connectionStrings>**

Answer (score 0):

From **MSDN**:

**SaveChanges** operates within a transaction. SaveChanges will roll back that transaction and throw an exception if any of the dirty ObjectStateEntry objects cannot be persisted

**SubmitChanges** starts a transaction and will roll back if an exception occurs while SubmitChanges is executing. However, this does not roll back the changes in memory or tracked by the DataContext; those changes will need to be rolled back manually. You can start with a new instance of the DataContext if the changes in memory are to be discarded.

You need to call **.SaveChanges()** instead of **.SubmitChanges()**

Modification to your code:

```
dc.UserDataClassesDataContext dc = new UserDataClassesDataContext();

dc.AddNewUser(Convert.ToInt32(tbId.Text),
          tbFirstName.Text,
          tbMiddleName.Text,
          tbLastName.Text,
          tbMail.Text,
          tbUserName.Text,
          tbPassword.Text);
dc.SaveChanges(); // Replace dc.SubmitChanges();
```